# Optimize in Stata / Mata

Tags: stata

I want write a loop in Stata with a Mata command 'optimize'. The basic syntax is (in .do file):

```
mata: x=runiform(100,2)
mata: F=J(rows(x),1,3)
mata: X=J(1,2,48)
mata: I=J(rows(x),1,1)

mata:
    void mysolver(todo, p, x, X, I, F, lnf, S, H)
        {
        factor = F :* (I + x*p')
        factor_bis= factor , factor
        Cuenta = x :* factor_bis
        Final=I'*Cuenta
        vvv  = Final - X
        lnf  = (vvv*vvv')[1,1]
        }

mata:
    S = optimize_init()
    optimize_init_evaluator(S, &mysolver())
    optimize_init_evaluatortype(S, "v0")
    optimize_init_params(S, J(1,2,0.01))
    optimize_init_which(S,  "min" )
    optimize_init_argument(S, 1, x)
    optimize_init_argument(S, 2, X)
    optimize_init_argument(S, 3, I)
    optimize_init_argument(S, 4, F)
    optimize_init_tracelevel(S,"none")
    optimize_init_conv_ptol(S, 1e-16)
    optimize_init_conv_vtol(S, 1e-16)
    xx=optimize(S)

    st_matrix("param_estim",xx)

end
```

How write a procedure 'optimizo' to be include in a loop:

```
forvalues i=(1)500 {
   ..... 
   optimizo
    }
```

to repeat 500 times the optimization? (in my application, the matrices change in each cycle)

Thank You.

Comment: Have you tried something already? If you have code that includes the loop that isn't working, we could try to figure out what's gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In your main code, instead of the line

```
xx=optimize(S)
```

Simply write this:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 500; i++) {

  [Do your matrix changes, call your optimize_init_argument commands if you need to change them]

  xx = optimize(S)
  xx
}
```